# Philosopher's Stone tooltip bug

Tags: league-of-legends

There is this new awesome map [Proving Ground](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Proving_Grounds).

In this game you start with enough gold to buy the [Philosopher's stone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone). But the tooltip for earned money starts counting without actually getting the money.

Is this a bug or do I get the money later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what others have stated, gold per 10 does in fact work on proving grounds. In Classic (Summoner's Rift/Twisted Treeline) the champion passively earns 13 gold per 10 seconds, in Dominion/Proving Grounds the passive gold is 56 gold per 10 seconds. This number is increased not only by gold per 10 items but also runes/masteries that have the same effect.

Also ARAM has nothing to do with the effectiveness of the stat.

Now about your actual question: You won't get the money later. The tooltip may inaccurately represent the amount you're getting before the gold starts actually rolling in when minions spawn. The total gold earned part of the tooltip is relatively new and Riot is known to have some bugs scattered around all over the place. But as far as I know the tooltip is accurate once minions spawn.

Comment: I have not noticed the GP/10 items working on the Murder Bridge, or for that matter, Dominion (but I have only played Dominion like 3 times). And if I recall correctly, they do not work because of the conflict with the Unique Passives on said items.

Comment: They do work, and it is easily tested in a custom game.  The bug where it starts counting gold earned on the item tooltip before minions spawn has been widely reported, but they have yet to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

GP10 Items do not work on this map since you already have increaased passive gold gain. Philo Stone and other gp10 items are still available tho cause they 1. give some decent stats 2. are upgraded into other items.

Comment: Is this true?  It really seems like when I start with Kage's LP, I end up with more gold...  Is there a link that can prove that GP items don't generate gold on the Proving Grounds?

Answer (score 2):

In AllRandomAllMid mode (which is the name used for the Proving Grounds Map) all the Items that provide static income in the normal game no longer do so.

Comment: Nope, Proving ground is playable as ARAM (all random all mid) this is the gamemode NOT the map name but also in blind pick and draft modes. Also these items are available.

Answer (score 1):

Riot created this map with ARAM in mind. As such, they saw fit to give everyone passive Gold per 10 and mana regen, with heals being half as effective to make the games go by more quickly.

In addition to that, they removed Wards and some AD items (The Bloodthirster and Madred's Bloodrazor being a couple), as well as making GP/10 item unique passives count against the map passive. Their mana/health regen/ health/critchance/AP is still given, but the UP GP/10 no longer do on that map.